# Increase the value of a record until certain average value is reached

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I need to increase the minimum salary by 15% until the average is >= 15000.
I know I need to put the avg in the loop but I am not quite sure how. My current code also returns ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes.

```
create or replace procedure avg_salary
as
v_avgsal number;
v_minsal number;
begin
select avg(salary),min(salary) into v_avgsal, v_minsal
from employees;
loop
 dbms_output.put_line(v_minsal);
 v_minsal:=v_minsal*1.15;
 exit when v_avgsal>=15000;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Unless you want to always increase the same person's salary you need to update and re-query the table each time round the loop. Initially the minimum salary is 2100. If you update that by 15% to 2415, the new minimum salary is for a different person, and is 2200; so which do you update the second time? Actually it's 2200 for two people (in the default HR schema), so you'd presumably update both of those to 2530. Now the minimum is 2400, and two people have that. Etc. The buffer overflow is because your loop never exits at the moment - at least until that exception is raised.

Comment: hint: calculate the total number of dollars that need to be added to all salaries to bring the average up. - then loop from lowest salary to highest until that number of dollars is allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should recalculate the avg inside the loop, or it will never break.
I believe you can achieve that returning the salary's sum and count(*).

1. Increase the variable where you'll return the sum by 15% of min_salary.
2. Divide it by the count of rows.
3. Step 2 will return the new avg - compare it with the value you want to break the loop.